# Does Rethinkdb support thousands of tables?

Tags: rethinkdb

Does RethinkDb support creating/managing thousands of tables?

Usecase: Tenant managed tables, without preknown schema.

**EDIT**

For future ref: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1861

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work, but RethinkDB wasn't designed for this use case and there's per-table memory overhead of about 12MB, so you may need a lot of memory on your server.

Answer (score 0):

It can support as many tables as you want, however there is an "overhead" with rethinkDB. From the docs:

> RethinkDB can handle databases much larger than the amount of main memory available on a server. However, some internal metadata is always kept in memory to guarantee fast access times. Every table has an overhead of 8 MB per server.

Lets just use 10MB for easy math. [Link to page](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/memory-usage/)

So you may want to change your schema just for simplicitys sake, if you are going to store commercial properties you dont need to store each property in a table, you should store each table in the way you are going to query them, so by state, or by property type, or by some other metric. I know you wouldnt do that but its just an example.

Also RethinkDB is designed to be horizontally scalable so if you do have thousands of tables RethinkDB will automatically scale across multiple servers for you.